# How to query records created within a work shift?

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails application that have an SQLite database that have a **Shifts** table, Which each Shift have a `beginning_at` column of value type of **Time** that indicates the hour the shift begins. And an `end_at` column also of value type of **Time** indicates the hour the shift ends.

The thing is actually this table have only two records; **Morning Shift** that `begins_at` 10 am and `ends_at` 5.30 pm same day. And the second record is `Evening Shift` that `begins_at` 6.30 pm and `ends_at` 2 am the next day.

Also I have **Orders** table that each order `belongs_to` a shift.

The problem is I want to have a controller action that can index all **Orders** that created from: **The beginning of which shift this action triggered at, Til the end of this shift.**

**The purpose of this action actually is to review the sales volume at the end of each working shift**

I've think it all over but I couldn't find the beginning point, Please help me. That is very crucial for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretend for the only possible solution ever, but try this one:

```
# orders.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shift

  scope :at_morning_shift, -> { where(shift: Shift.morning).order('created_at asc') }
  scope :at_night_shift, -> { where(shift: Shift.night).order('created_at asc') }

  def self.current_shift
    begins_time, ends_time = Shift.morning.begins_at, Shift.morning.ends_at
    if (begins_time.hour..ends_time.hour).cover?(Time.now.hour)
      Order.at_morning_shift
    else
      Order.at_night_shift
    end
  end
end


# shift.rb
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  def self.morning
    find_by_name("Morning shift")
  end

  def self.night
    find_by_name("Night shift")
  end

end

# orders_controller.rb
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @orders = Order.current_shift
  end
end
```

Here is the console output:

```
[86] pry(main)> Time.now.utc
=> 2016-08-22 05:05:50 UTC
[87] pry(main)> Order.current_shift
  Shift Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE "shifts"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "Morning shift"]]
  Shift Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE "shifts"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "Morning shift"]]
  Shift Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE "shifts"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "Night shift"]]
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."shift_id" = 2  ORDER BY created_at asc
=> [#<Order:0x007fbdc88888c0 id: 1, name: "molestiae", phone: nil, product_id: nil, created_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:32:53 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:32:53 UTC +00:00, shift_id: 2>,
 #<Order:0x007fbdc8888730 id: 5, name: "explicabo", phone: nil, product_id: nil, created_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, shift_id: 2>,
 #<Order:0x007fbdc8888578 id: 6, name: "cupiditate", phone: nil, product_id: nil, created_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, shift_id: 2>,
 #<Order:0x007fbdc88883e8 id: 7, name: "rerum", phone: nil, product_id: nil, created_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, shift_id: 2>,
 #<Order:0x007fbdc8888258 id: 8, name: "totam", phone: nil, product_id: nil, created_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, shift_id: 2>,
 #<Order:0x007fbdc88880c8 id: 9, name: "inventore", phone: nil, product_id: nil, created_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, shift_id: 2>,
 #<Order:0x007fbdc8883ed8 id: 11, name: "saepe", phone: nil, product_id: nil, created_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 04:33:40 UTC +00:00, shift_id: 2>]
[88] pry(main)>
```

Please bear in mind that you should pay attention to the time_zone of your app and client. But the basic approach will remain the same.

Comment: thank you for your very helpful answer It works very fine, Except it retrieve all records created on the current shift even it was created a week ago. I was hoping to retrieve only the past shift's order only.

Comment: Shifts created every day? EG today you'll have two shifts and tomorrow you will have another two shifts? So your DB will have two new shifts every day?

Comment: No, I mean to limit results to only Orders created in the past morning or evening shift. I was trying to tweak the query and I came up with ... `Order.where("created_at >= ? AND shift_id = ?", Time.current.in_time_zone("Zone").beginning_of_day, Shift.morning` , It worked fine in the console but when i put it in the scope the model simply ignores the creation date!

Comment: Sorry dear, but are you suggesting to have two new shifts every day? Or you just asking. Which is better in your opinion?

Comment: I'm just asking. I think it's better to have just two shifts and apply each of them according to order creation time.

Comment: One more point. AR stores data in UTC in the DB and rails is just making offset according to the app timezone. But your example works fine for me. I'm getting right orders